# Is it more performant to require assets (like images) inside a component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, performance

Requiring an asset outside of a component:

```js
const img = require("img.png")

const Component = () => <Image src={img} />
```

Requiring an asset inside of a component, with or without using useMemo

```js
const Component = () => {
 const img = useMemo(() => require("img.png"), [])

 return <Image src={img} />
}
```

What if there are like 10 images per Screen/Component, if we require them outside of the component, do they get unmounted?